# how to check that xml string contains declaration tag or not?

Tags: c#

I want to check that my xml string contains the declartion tag or not?
My xml string has multiple root node, So I can't load that string into XmlDocument.

My problem is: I have an xml with multiple root nodes and I need to do some processing on this xml. So in code, I am adding a root node manually and after processing I am removing that root node. So before adding the root node, i need to check that xml contains the declartion tag or not?

Answer (score 0):

- 1. Load your xml to a string with a FileStream and TextReader
- 2. Append a wrapper xml tag before and after the string

  string wrappedXml = "<wrapper>" + loadedXml + "</wrapper>";
- 3. Now load wrappedXml to an XElement via XElement.Parse

Now you can work with your xml and just treat each first child as a root (logically).

You need to do this to be able to check if it's there.  Otherwise you are going to have to do some manually string parsing.

No matter how you do it though, in some way or form that file is going to get loaded into memory.  So you might as well just load it with a wrapper and use the API to figure it out as opposed to doing a manual parse.

Comment: I want to remove Xml declaration i.e. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: I am getting the below error, if string contains xml declaration.. "Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it."

Comment: Parse it to an XDocument instead of an XElement.